# 2 legend but only show the text in one

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have this plot

```
 dummy = data.frame(group=c("A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J"),
           y = c(80,75,68,62,75,71,73,69,60,78),
           x=c(30, 32,36,34,28,41,35,29,22,33),
           size =c(8,5,7,2,3,2,4,6,9,10)
           )

ggplot(dummy,aes(x=x,y=y,color=group, size = size)) + 
  geom_point()
```

I do not want the text of the size legend to appear. So I don't want 2,4,6,8 10 to appear in the size legend. I STILL want the circle and the sizes.

How can I make that happen?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is lots of useful information in `?guides` and `?guide_legend`:

```
ggplot(dummy,aes(x=x,y=y,color=group, size = size)) + 
  geom_point() +
  guides(size = guide_legend(label.theme = element_blank()))
```

Comment: that removes the text which is good but it also removes the title of title of the size legend which is bad. Is there a way to make the title of the size legend appear?

Comment: @user3022875 Yes, specify a title using the `title` argument to `guide_legend`.